# How can I develop custom passport-local authentication strategy for use with my REST API

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm using the Express framework to create a REST API that will be used to ingest client data. My API will require the formatting below. I would like to create an authentication strategy with passport that can be used to parse out the login token email and password. Request example below.

```
{
    "security": {
        "loginToken": {
            "email": "test@email.com",
            "password": "testpassword"
        },
        "accessToken": {
            "apiAccessKey": "api_access_key_here"
        } 
    },
    "data": {
        "partners": [
            {
                "partner_id":"testvalue1",
                "tech":"testvalue2"
            },
            {
                "partner_id":"testvalue3",
                "tech":"testvalue4"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The standard passport.authenticate function doesn't seem to work for this because "email" and "password" are nested in the JSON request. Can I somehow specify in the local authentication strategy `email: req.body.security.loginToken.email`? Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

for this situation you should use [passport-json](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-json)

1- npm i passport-json

2- require("passport-json").Strategy

3- change custom fields like this :

```
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-json").Strategy;
const customFields = {
  usernameProp : "security.loginToken.email",
  passwordProp : "security.loginToken.password"
}
const verifyCallback = (username, password, done)=>{
   //your verify
}
const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields , verifyCallback);
```

4. change route

```
app.post(
  '/login', 
  passport.authenticate('json', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  }
);
```